# Iterate and add to string

Tags: java

I'm trying to return information about the customers in the database and the information is presented sorted by customer name. I used `Collection.sort` to sort my data but when I do iterate through customers to add to `mediaIlog` and return it, I got an error which said the method must return a value of type `String` even when I return a string. Can some one help me?

```
//collection.sort
public class Customer implements Comparable<Customer>
{
    public Customer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int compareTo(Customer ot) {
        String name1 = this.name;
        String name2 = ot.name;
        return name1.compareTo(name2);
    }
}
```

This is the method I used to iterate through customers to add to `mediaIlog` and to return it and it gave me the error described above.

```
ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

public String getAllCustomers()
{
    String mediaIlog = "";
    for (Customer P : customers)
        return mediaIlog.add(P);    
}
```

Comment: [`java.lang.String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) doesn't have method `add`. What is `String` used here?

Comment: you are trying to return a function inside a loop.. you need to close the loop with all of the adding completed before returning the String

Answer (score 1):

Use a StringBuffer to accumulate your String. Assumming your class Customer has a toString method properly implemmented:

```
public String getAllCustomers(){
    StringBuffer mediaIlog = new StringBuffer();
      for (Customer P : customers){
        mediaIlog.append(P);
      }

    return mediaIlog.toString()

}
```

Comment: You really should be using StringBuilder, unless you need thread safety.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are returning something wrong, you should do something like

```
public String getAllCustomers()
{
    String mediaIlog = "";
    for (Customer P : customers){
        mediaIlog += P;
    }
    return mediaIlog;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers already given, here is an alternative way of doing it:

```
public String getAllCustomers()
{
    return this.customers.stream()
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Java [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) are a very powerful tool. You can easily expand this example like so:

```
return this.customers.stream()
        .filter(Customer::hasOrders)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Customer::getRevenue))
        .limit(10)
        .map(customer -> customer.getFirstName() + " " + customer.getLastName())
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

This would return a comma separated top 10 list of customers first and last name having an order but low revenue.